# How can i perform a[i&j] += b[i] * c[j] efficiently for every i and j?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitmask

I have two integer arrays `b` and `c` with a size of less than 1024. I want to find a new array `a` efficiently such that I have `a[i&j] += b[i] * c[j]` for every 0 <= i , j <= 1024. I'm looking for a solution other than regular O(n^2).

Basically I wish to improve this:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i){
   for(int j = 0; j < 1024; ++j){
      a[i&j] += b[i] * c[j];
   }
}
```

Comment: but many `i&j` give the same value, what do you want to do if, say `a[0]==1`, `b[0]==1` and `b[1]==0` (`0&0==0` and `0&1==0`). should `c[0]` be zero or one?

Comment: @Phylliida sorry for not asking properly i want to add all the values which are same. i have updated the question with code. assuming a is zero initialised.

Comment: ok that makes more sense, do you have a guarantee on the types of the arrays? (8-byte ints, 16-byte ints, 32-byte ints, floating points etc.)

Comment: @Phylliida arrays are 32/64 bit integers.

Comment: if you `want to find a new array` then how on earth `a[i]` has its value before so that you can add with `b[i] * c[j]`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid no. Since you want to add `b[i]` and `c[j]` for *every possible combination* of `i` and `j`, you must iterate through all of them. There's little you can improve, though.

There's a better approach if you only want a specific `a[n]`, but not the whole array `a`.

```c
int n = 666; // Input
// Split input into bits
int e[10] = {};
for (int i = 0, ne = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if ((n & (1<<i)) == 0)
        e[ne++] = i; // Store the indices of zero bits of input
}
```

Now create `b[i]` and `c[j]` from the input:

```c
int i, j;
// Enumerate all possible combinations of i and j
for (int count = 0; count < pow(3, ne); count++){
    int t = count;
    i = j = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < ne; k++) {
        switch (t % 3) {
            case 0: break;
            case 1:
                i |= 1 << k;
                break;
            case 2:
                j |= 1 << k;
                break;
        }
        t /= 3;
    }
    i |= n, j |= n;
    a[n] += b[i] * c[j];
}
```